# Emacs ESS markdown, cant make pdf

Tags: r, emacs, markdown, knitr, ess

I am trying to knit a pdf from Emacs/ess. I can knit the file using RStudio to make a pdf. Using Emacs I can weave it and export it (C-c C-c e), but it exports as a .txt
Here is an example code:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "SB"
date: "Wednesday, February 04, 2015"
output: pdf_document
---

You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r}
summary(cars)
```

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r, echo=FALSE}
plot(cars)
```
````

How do I export as a .pdf?

Comment: I was able to get it by opening an R process and using render from the rmarkdown package. is there a way to run it from the within the same emacs process as the .rmd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you'll need to go outside of ESS for this:

> Libraries for literate data analysis are obsolete and not loaded by default. This includes `ess-noweb`, `ess-swv`, and related functionality like `Rnw-mode`. Users are encouraged to switch to one of several other packages that deal with these modes. For example, polymode https://github.com/polymode/poly-R/, https://polymode.github.io/, or markdown-mode with edit-indirect https://jblevins.org/projects/markdown-mode.

Polymode/poly-R lists support for several weavers:

> Weavers:
>
> - `knitr`
> - `knitr-ESS`
> - `Sweave-ESS`
> - `Sweave`